# How do I create subfolders with parent folder's name added in the beginning?

Tags: linux, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to create subfolders under each parent folder with parent folder's name added in the beginning.

Name of the parent folder
Week 1

Subfolders to be created 
Week 1_of_1
Week 1_of_2

I am trying to do this with all the parent folders in the folder which goes from Week 1 to Week 17. 
I have a command that I am playing with but cannot make it work

```
for d in */; do mkdir "$d/d_of_1" "$d/d_of_2";done
```

This just creates d_of_1 and d_of_2 as subfolders.
How do make sure that d is the name of parent folder name?

Comment: Personally, I can't quite understand what you are trying to achieve, but this sort of problem is best solved by `echo`ing your cmd, until is is right, so `for d in */; do echo mkdir "$d/d_of_1" "$d/d_of_2";done`. Don't forget that you need to dbl-quote "Week 1" with `\"Week 1\"` etc. When the output is correct, the send via pipe to temp shell, i.e. `for ... ; done | bash` . A complete list of input dirs/files and expected output dir files would make you Q easier to understand, and of course you'd only need to illustrate dir1-dir4 to make the problem clear. Good luck.

Comment: You are missing a $

Comment: "Week 17/Week 17 of 2" Sounds quite strange

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for d in */; do mkdir -p "$d/${d}_of_1" "$d/${d}_of_2"; done
```